# Doctrine is not finding @UniqueEntity in my class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using this in User.php

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
* @ORM\Table(name="user")
* @UniqueEntity("email")
```

But i am getting this error

> [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
>         [Semantical Error] The annotation "@UniqueEntity" in class ...\Entity\User was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a
>   "use" st
>         atement for this annotation?

I even tried ORM\UniqueEntity but it also didn't worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its not Doctrine Constraint But Symfony's

Check [UniqueEntity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) constraint.

```
// DON'T forget this use statement!!!
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
```